# Use scanf to scan a word only but with space at the front

Tags: c, text, scanf

Is it possible to scan in text with space(s) + a word only in C?

here is the sample text:

```
"Oh my   god!"
```

Here is the function:

```
...declarations...malloc...etc.
for (int i = 0; ; i++)
{
    some_scanf_func(s, "%some format", input);
    c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF)
        break;
    else
        ungetc(c, stdin);
}
```

So that my input is:

```
"Oh" when i = 0;

" my" when i = 1;

"   god!" when i = 2;
```

Space is at the front of the word. Punctuaions are counted as valid characters.

Thank you chux for the trick, and thank you Charlie for your answer.

Comment: read the line with fgets, scan it with strtok.

Comment: @CharlieBurns: Using `strtok()` blats (zaps, overwrites) the separators; the whole string is needed so you can't readily use `strtok()` here.

Comment: What do you want as output if there are several spaces between each word?  Why do you think the leading spaces are important, because they definitely make this into a hard problem?

Comment: @CharlieBurns, that might not work, if my input string is something like "Oh     my god!  "

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"%*s%n"`.

`%*s` skips for leading white space, then scans for non-whtespace text.  The `*` says not to say the result.

`%n` says to record the position of the scan (if we ever get there).

```
char input[100];
char *p = input;
int count = 0;
if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) == NULL) {
  ;  // handle EOF
}
while (*p)  {
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(p, "%*s%n", &n);
  if (n == 0) break;
  p = &p[n];
  count++;
  }
```

---

To isolate the word with `buffer`

```
char *previousp; 
while (*p)  {
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(p, "%*s%n", &n);
  if (n == 0) break;
  previousp = p
  p = &p[n];
  // At this point `previousp` to p is OP desired output.
  printf(%.*s\n", p - previousp, previousp);
  count++;
  }
```

---

OP wanted to use `sscanf()` but simply marching down the buffer as suggested by @Charlie Burns makes sense.

```
const char *p = buffer;
while (*p) {
  const char *endp = p;
  while (isspace(*endp)) endp++;
  while (*endp && !isspace(*endp)) endp++;
  // At this point `p` to `endp` is OP desired output.
  printf(%.*s\n", endp - p, p);
  p = endp;
}
```

Comment: +1 clever.  It would be kind to show how to isolate the words. I can't see a reason why `sscanf()` would ever return anything other than zero as long as `p` is not a null pointer (which it shouldn't be).  A curious quirky use of some relatively obscure features of `sscanf()`, but they do the job nicely.  You couldn't do this doing direct input with `scanf()`; that would lose the characters making up the word.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int foo(char *s, char **result, int size) {
        char *p1 = s;
        int count = 0;
        while(*p1 && count < size-1) {
                char *p2 = p1;
                for( ; *p2 && isspace(*p2); p2++);
                if(*p2) {
                        for( ; *p2 && isspace(*p2) == 0; p2++);
                        result[count++] = strndup(p1, p2 - p1);
                }
                p1 = p2;
        }
        result[i] = 0;
        return count;
}

int main(void) {
        char *result[100];
        int n = foo("  Oh my   god! ", result, 100);
        for(int i = 0; i != n; i++) {
                printf("%d '%s'\n", i, result[i]);
                free(result[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Kind of ugly I suppose. But it prints

```
0 '  Oh'
1 ' my'
2 '   god!'
```

And does the right thing with the original input too.

Answer (score 1):

Read it into a string - then parse it.

You can use sscanf() to parse a string in the same was as scanf, after detecting if there is a space